# Fixed Footer Not Showing All Of Section?

Tags: html, css

Thanks to the man who fixed this problem it worked on Google Chrome but on IE it is still not working. The question was answered for one browser. If you go and look at my site in the newest IE http://www.bbwillowlake.co.nf you can see that you can not see the very bottom of the site. I am still wondering why the site is doing this. Do i just need to add more margin at the bottom? I am trying to reword these questions because i got my accounted banned. Also below is a version of the newest code lots of changes. BTW the copyright is fake i know that some people wont touch code with the copyright because it is illegal this copyright is fake this is just a fake website for a school project.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>
B & B Willow Lake | Home
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/layout.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<header id="header">
<h1><a href="index.php"><font color="#FFFFFF">B & B Willow Lake</font></a></h1>
</header>
<ul id="menu">
<li>
<a href="packages.php">Packages</a>
<ul>  
<li><a href="one_and_two_night.php">One and Two Night</a>
</li>
<li><a href="anniversary.php">Anniversary</a>
</li>
<li><a href="extended_stay.php">Extended Stay</a>
</li>
<li><a href="honey_moon.php">Honey Moon</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="activities.php">Activities</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="indoor.php">Indoor</a>
</li>
<li><a href="outdoor.php">Outdoor</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="dine.php">Dine</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="specials.php">Specials</a>
</li>
<li><a href="breakfast.php">BreakFast</a>
</li>
<li><a href="lunch.php">Lunch</a>
</li>
<li><a href="teaparty.php">Tea Party</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="contact_us.php">Contact Us</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="directions.php">Directions</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<section id="section_slide">
<img src="images/background.jpg" alt="background" id="png1"><img src="images/background3.jpg" alt="background2" id="png3"><img src="images/background2.jpg" alt="background3" id="png2"><img src="images/background4.jpg" alt="background4" id="png4">
</section>
<div id="middle_wrapper">
<section id="section">
<article>
<h2>Play</h2>
<a href="play.html"><img src="images/play.jpg" id="png5" alt="background5" id="picmain"></a>
<p>Here will go a text area that talks about all the stuff they can do out door and in door most of the descrpiton will be like the descrpition on the acrives page which it is refing to,<br />
<a id="learnmore" href="play.php">Learn More</a>
</p></article><hr /> 
<article>
<h2>Stay</h2><a href="stay.php"><img src="images/stay.jpg" id="png6" alt="background6" id="picmain2"></a>
<p>This wil be a ref to the package page just a shorter descrpiton so sum up what our stay is like all of these little text areas like play stay dine and cel shoul have a blue text area at the bottom that says learn more that when liked should link to the main page for the subject.<br />
<a id="learnmore2" href="stay.php">Learn More</a>
</p><hr /></article>
<article>
<h2>Dine</h2><a href="dine.php"><img src="images/dine.jpg" id="png7" alt="background7" id="picmain3"></a>
<p>Here will be a desc of the dine page which well tell the user the basics of what eating is like at the resort b and b willow lake it should also tell them that there is a kids menu for there kids and that there is fine dining for the adults and a lot of places to eat for the famlily and just for lovers to get away and eat.<br />
<a id="learnmore3" href="dine.php">Learn More</a>
</p><hr /></article>
<article>
<h2>Celebrate</h2><a href="cel.php"><img src="images/cel.jpg" id="png8" alt="background8" id="picmain4"></a>
<p>This well talk about the events that you can host and the resort like wewdings and birth days tea partys any thing from normal kids birth day partys to highclass wedingns and events of any sort.<br />
<a id="learnmore4" href="celebrate.php">Learn More</a>
</p></article>
</section>
<aside id="aside">
<br />
<br />
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Packages">Packages</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
    <option value="One and Two Night">One and Two Night $1,000.00 USD</option>
    <option value="Anniversary">Anniversary $1,000.00 USD</option>
    <option value="Extended Stay">Extended Stay $1,000.00 USD</option>
    <option value="Honey Moon">Honey Moon $1,000.00 USD</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7-----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-----END PKCS7-----
">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>

<br />
<br />
<br />
<h2>Why Us?</h2>
<p>
<pre>
adsfsdafasdfadfsdafasfsdafasdfa<br />dfsdafadfdddddddujhyjbddddddd<br />dddddddddddddddddddddddd<br />
asdfasdfsdafadsdfasdfdsfadsfasdfa<br />dfadsfasdfadfda<br />sfasdfasdfasdfasdfsdafsdafdsafd<br />
dsasdfdsfsdfasdfasdfdfddddddddddddd<br />ddddddddddddddddddddddddd<br />dddddddddddd<br />
dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd<br />Sddddddddddddddddddddddddd<br />ddddddddddddddd<br />
</pre>
</p>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<iframe title="Youtube video player" width="90%" height="390px" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mI6aVSzZsps&list=TLctir32a34lOmJXkxNcviVk5lubS_IL3N"></iframe>
<img src="images/facebook.gif" alt="facebook" id="facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/"><img src="images/twitter.gif" alt="twitter" id="twitter" href="http://www.twitter.com/"><img src="images/g+.gif" alt="g+" id="google" href="http://www.google.com/"><img src="images/youtube.gif" alt="youtube" id="youtube" href="http://www.youtube.com/"><br />
</aside>
</div>
</div>
<footer id="footer">
<h1><a href="index.php"><font color="#FFFFFF">B & B Willow Lake</font></a></h1>
<p>
bandbwillowlake@gmail.com
</p>
<p>
Copyright 0 B.C. &copy; bbwillowlake.co.nf, All rights reserved.
</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

BTW sorry for the sloppy code in my style.

style.css

```
*{
font-family:Verdana;
}
body {  
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(#D8D8D8, #A4A4A4, #6E6E6E); /* Safari */
background: -o-radial-gradient(#D8D8D8, #A4A4A4, #6E6E6E); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-radial-gradient(#D8D8D8, #A4A4A4, #6E6E6E); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: radial-gradient(#D8D8D8, #A4A4A4, #6E6E6E); /* Standard syntax */
}
pre {
    overflow-x: auto; /* Use horizontal scroller if needed */
    white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
    white-space : normal;
}  
#header{
color: #FFF;
background: #111;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#5882FA, #3D72A4); 
background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #5882FA),color-stop(1, #3D72A4));    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#5882FA, #3D72A4);  
background: -o-linear-gradient(#5882FA, #3D72A4);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#5882FA, #3D72A4);
background: linear-gradient(#5882FA, #3D72A4);
}
#facebook{
width:50px;
height:50PX;
margin-left:5px;
}
#twitter{
width:50px;
height:50PX;
margin-left:5px;
}
#google{
width:50px;
height:50PX;
margin-left:5px;
}
#youtube{
width:50px;
height:50PX;
margin-left:5px;
}
#picmain{
text-align:center;
width:150px;
height:150px;
}
#picmain2{
text-align:center;
width:150px;
height:150px;
}
#picmain3{
text-align:center;
width:150px;
height:150px;
}
#picmain4{
text-align:center;
width:150px;
height:150px;
}

h1{
color: #FFF;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
text-decoration:none;
}
h2{
color: #000;
margin-bottom:8px;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}
#nav{
background-color: #254159;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: center;
}
a{
text-decoration:none;
}
a:link{
text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
text-decoration: underline;
}
#section_slide{
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
img{
}
#section{
background-color: #FFF;
}
#png1{
width:25%;
height:150px;
}
#png2{
width:25%;
height:150px;
}
#png3{
width:25%;
height:150px;
}
#png4{
width:25%;
height:150px;
}
#png5{
width:150px;
height:150px;
transition:width 2s, height 2s, transform 2s;
-webkit-transition:width 2s, height 2s, -webkit-transform 2s; /* Safari */
}
#png5:hover{
width:250px;
height:250px;
transform:rotate(360deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); /* Safari */
}
#png6{
width:150px;
height:150px;
transition:width 2s, height 2s, transform 2s;
-webkit-transition:width 2s, height 2s, -webkit-transform 2s; /* Safari */
}
#button{
width:auto;
height:25px;
background: #111;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #111); 
background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #111),color-stop(1, #444));  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
background: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
background: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
color:#FFF;
}
#png6:hover{
width:250px;
height:250px;
transform:rotate(360deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); /* Safari */
}
img{
border: none;
}
#png7{
width:150px;
height:150px;
transition:width 2s, height 2s, transform 2s;
-webkit-transition:width 2s, height 2s, -webkit-transform 2s; /* Safari */
}
#png7:hover{
width:250px;
height:250px;
transform:rotate(360deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); /* Safari */
}
#png8{
width:150px;
height:150px;
transition:width 2s, height 2s, transform 2s;
-webkit-transition:width 2s, height 2s, -webkit-transform 2s; /* Safari */
}
#png8:hover{
width:250px;
height:250px;
transform:rotate(360deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); /* Safari */
}
#aside{
background: #111;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#5882FA, #3D72A4); 
background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #5882FA),color-stop(1, #3D72A4));    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#5882FA, #3D72A4);  
background: -o-linear-gradient(#5882FA, #3D72A4);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#5882FA, #3D72A4);
background: linear-gradient(#5882FA, #3D72A4);
}
#footer{
background: #111;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #111); 
background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #111),color-stop(1, #444));  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
background: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
background: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
color:#FFFFFF;
}
#menu{
width: 82%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding: 10px 0 0 0;
list-style: none;  
background: #111;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #111); 
background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #111),color-stop(1, #444));  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
background: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
background: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
-moz-border-radius: 50px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
}

#menu li{
float: left;
padding: 0 0 10px 0;
position: relative;
}

#menu a{
float: left;
height: 25px;
padding: 0 25px;
color: #999;
text-transform: uppercase;
font: bold 12px/25px Arial, Helvetica;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}

#menu li:hover > a{
color: #FFF;
}

*html #menu li a:hover{ /* IE6 */
color: #FFFFFF;
}

#menu li:hover > ul{
display: block;
}

/* Sub-menu */

#menu ul{
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;    
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 35px;
left: 0;
z-index: 99999;    
background: #FFFFFF;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #111),color-stop(1, #444));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
background: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #111); 
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
background: linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
}

#menu ul li{
float: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: block;  
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111111, 0 2px 0 #777777;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111111, 0 2px 0 #777777;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111111, 0 2px 0 #777777;
}

#menu ul li:last-child{   
-moz-box-shadow: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;    
}

#menu ul a{    
padding: 10px;
height: auto;
line-height: 1;
display: block;
white-space: nowrap;
float: none;
text-transform: none;
}

*html #menu ul a{ /* IE6 */   
height: 10px;
width: 150px;
}

*:first-child+html #menu ul a{ /* IE7 */    
height: 10px;
width: 150px;
}

.button{
border-radius:10px;
background-color:red;
}

#menu ul a:hover{
background: #111;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#5882FA, #3D72A4); 
background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #5882FA),color-stop(1, #3D72A4));    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#5882FA, #3D72A4);  
background: -o-linear-gradient(#5882FA, #3D72A4);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#5882FA, #3D72A4);
background: linear-gradient(#5882FA, #3D72A4);
}

#menu ul li:first-child a{
-moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

#menu ul li:first-child a:after{
content: '';
position: absolute;
left: 30px;
top: -8px;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 5px solid transparent;
border-right: 5px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 8px solid #444;
}

#menu ul li:first-child a:hover:after{
border-bottom-color: #FFF;
}

#menu ul li:last-child a{
-moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

/* Clear floated elements */
#menu:after{
visibility: hidden;
display: block;
font-size: 0;
content: " ";
clear: both;
height: 0;
}

#learnmore{
color: blue;
}

#learnmore2{
color: blue;
}

#learnmore3{
color: blue;
}

#learnmore4{
color: blue;
}
* html #menu             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html #menu { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */
```

Comment: <p>
bandbwillowlake@gmail.com
</p>
<p>
Copyright &copy bandbwillowlake.co.nf
</p> is missing

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine

```
#section {
    margin-bottom: 100px
}
```

It will create a space between footer and the end of section.

Comment: Please look at the new version i added and the new stuff please and thank you and how do i get unbanned?

Comment: hi..sorry for a little late answer, i just saw this comment. There is a similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141963/ie7-positionfixed-and-margin-top-problem/7142019#7142019. Looking at this solution , similarly you can remove the margin-bottom from the #section, add padding-bottom to body